# Why is the body tag of my site not stretching 100% high?

Tags: css, height

I'm trying to figure out why the body tag of my site in FF (Mac) doesn't stretch the height of the window? Can anyone see why?

I'm currently in the process of browser-checking the site, so hearing about any other weird stuff would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT: Sorry, hit submit before I added the link:

http://www.rocketmovie.com

Comment: It would help to see some code.

Comment: Can you show some code or give a link?

Comment: Sorry, I just realised I didn't include the link! Here it is: http://www.rocketmovie.com

Answer (score 6):

It's a lot of tutorials of the '100% height'. Probably you need set 100% height to `HTML` also.

Here are couple of them:

[100% Height Layout Using CSS](http://www.dave-woods.co.uk/index.php/100-height-layout-using-css/)

[Quick Tip: CSS 100% Height](http://www.tutwow.com/htmlcss/quick-tip-css-100-height/)

Comment: Hi @Samrich, thanks for responding. Unfortunately, it's not that - take a look at my CSS and you'll see I'm doing that already...any other ideas?

Comment: your `.maincontent` doesn't have height property